# What is the difference between a file with .dist and without

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-6, laravel-nova

I'm trying to learn more about package development by using Laravel Nova as a bit of a guide. I'm confused as to how Nova's assets are compiled, and part of that confusion stems from Nova not having a `webpack.mix.js` but instead a `webpack.mix.js.dist`.

I'm trying to model this within my package in order to compile and publish my assets for use in my project, but I get npm errors when trying to run any command

```
Cannot find module 'dir/dir/dir/package/webpack.mix'
```

I'm unsure as to why it is looking for this file in the first place, but it still seems to be an issue. To get to the root of why this is an issue and how I can fix this, I'd like to know what the difference between `webpack.mix.js` and `webpack.mix.js.dist` is.

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Files that end in '.dist' are generally the default distribution files that come from the package and should not be edited. They will be overwritten on package updates.

You can use them as a reference to add or replace configuration in your primary file(s).

From what I can gather, Laravel Nova creates it's real webpack.mix.js from this file when you activate a certain feature. (It's a paid product, I do not have a license to see it, I can only skim the documents.)